# Do these kalanchoes look normal or healthy?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, watering, kalanchoe

I have several kalanchoes and am having different problems with them. [image: photo of kalanchoe plant number 1]

[image: photo of kalanchoe plant number 2]

They are two different plants. I planted them a month ago. Do the leaves of the plant look normal or healthy? I ask because I think they are folded(?). If so, then what is the problem? Is it under-watered or over-watered?

The pots have drainage holes. They are under 38-40 degrees full sun as I have been said that they can handle it. I water each one everyday once as the soil gets cracked up from drying.